# Pick Max Date from Table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table variable defined thus

```
DECLARE @DatesTable TABLE
(
    Id uniqueidentifier,
    FooId uniqueidentifier,
    Date date,
    Value decimal (26, 10)
)
```

Id is always unique but FooId is duplicated throughout the table.  What I would like to do is to select * from this table for each unique FooId having the max(date).  So, if there are 20 rows with 4 unique FooIds then I'd like 4 rows, picking the row for each FooId where the date is the largest.

I've tried using group by but I kept getting errors about various fields not being in the select clause etc.

Comment: If you have more than say... 100 rows or so in that variable, you may want to consider a temp table. Especially if you start seeing performance issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a common table expression with `row_number()`:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT Id, FooId, Date, Value,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FooId ORDER BY Date DESC) As rn
    FROM  @DatesTable
)

SELECT Id, FooId, Date, Value
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I now finally have understood what CTEs are for.  Thank you.

Comment: @SachinKainth a cte can be used for other things as well - a recursive query for one thing. If it's not recursive, it's mainly to simplify the writing of a query. (in this case, it could be replaced with a derived table, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

Often the most efficient method is a correlated subquery:

```
select dt.*
from @DatesTable dt
where dt.date = (select max(dt2.date) from @DatesTable dt2 where dt2.fooid = dt.fooid);
```

However, for this to be efficient, you need an index on `(fooid, date)`.  In more recent versions of SQL Server, you can have indexes on table variables.  In earlier versions, you can do this using a primary key.